# terminal not displaying outputs properly

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal, lxqt

terminal is not displaying outputs properly, it displays outputs mostly like given in the image below

[image]

while it should display outputs like this

[image]

any suggestions on  how it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you set the `COLUMNS` environment variable to something less than the width of your terminal?  Does the issue resolve itself if you first do `unset -v COLUMNS`? Or, is the issue that you are using a font that doesn't have a fixed width (not a monospaced font)?

Comment: No I have not.
I tried `unset -v COLUMNS` it is still the same. the font I'm using is the default font that came with it.

Comment: Is it a gui terminal where system font is used? Can you change it to monospace (regular)?

Comment: It is QTerminal, I have tried and changed it to all monospaced fonts including monospace but the outputs are still the same. @thanasisp

Answer (score 1):

You are using a proportionally spaced font, and what you want is a monospaced font.

From an open QTerminal window:

- click `File`, then `Preferences`; the `Appearance` tab should display
- the top line should be the `Font` selection; the default shown on my installation is `Liberation Mono 12 pt`
- click `Change...` and select a monospaced font, such as `Liberation Mono` or `Courier 10 Pitch`
- click `OK`, then `Apply`, then `OK`.  This should return you to your QTerminal session.

Test with the output of `ps` or similar command and ensure that the columns align.

Confirm that your font choice is recorded in QTerminal's settings:

```
$ grep ^font ~/.config/qterminal.org/qterminal.ini 
fontFamily=Courier 10 Pitch
fontSize=12
```